# JPA search String, Long and Boolean

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpql

I have a Spring-Boot app. There's an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long schoolId;
    private Boolean isActive;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I have a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepositoryPageable extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

I need to make a request to search by `schoolId` and filter **all fields** by some string.

Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u " +
        "WHERE u.schoolId = :schoolId AND (" +
        "u.id like %:searchVal% OR " +
        "u.name like %:searchVal% OR " +
        "u.isActive like %:searchVal%)")
Page<User> getUserBySchoolIdWithFilter(@Param("schoolId") Long schoolId,
                                       Pageable pageable,
                                       @Param("searchVal") String searchVal);
```

But I receive an exception because I try to apply `like` to `Long` and `Boolean`.

**For example**, if I try to filter by "testSearchValue", I receive this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%testSearchValue%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)

Unfortunately, `CAST` and `CONVERT` haven't worked for me.

So is there any workaround?

**SOME DETAILS**

I send a `GET` request to this API:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "users/{schoolId}/search", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<Page<User>> searchUserBySchoolWithFilter(
                    @PathVariable(value = "schoolId") Long schoolId, Pageable pageable,
                    @RequestParam(value = "searchVal", required = false) String searchVal) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService
                .getUserBySchoolIdWithFilter(schoolId, pageable, searchVal), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Then in `UserService`:

```
public Page<User> getUserBySchoolIdWithFilter(Long schoolId, Pageable pageable, String searchVal) {
    return userRepositoryPageable.getUserBySchoolIdWithFilter(schoolId, pageable, searchVal);
}
```

**So:**

As far as I see it, the basic point of the question is to represent `Long` and `Boolean` as `String`.
Maybe it's better to use `nativeQuery`? If so, then could you give me a hint about how to use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` with `LIKE` clause?

Comment: Try to read an exception message and understand what exactly is going wrong. Then you can proceed with fixing the issue.

Comment: @AntonHlinisty, I've edited the question and added an exception. It's pretty obvious one.

Comment: Well, first of all i think it is wrong to apply like on id columns, always equals. Also, why use like when you can use `=` for booleans?

Comment: @RaulCuth yes, I understand that it's wrong, I've given it as an example of what I want to achieve. And if we're talking about booleans, I want the records with `isActive = false` to appear in search results when I filter, for example, by `fal` value.

Comment: @htshame that's not a realistic requirement. For example, non-English speakers would not enter tru or fal to test for true or false. Change the way your UI works. Users shouldn't be entering the English representation of a boolean on your specific database to search for true/false values. They should check a checkbox. The ID should be purely technical, too.

Comment: @JBNizet you have a point. I guess the initial requirements will change, but in the mean time, I have a pretty dumb frontend datatable component with pagination, that takes all the data from database, represents everything as string and has a single Search field that filters all the the columns. And now I need to move the pagination to backend, saving all the existing functionality. It simply becomes interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered the usage of [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html)?

Using specifications, you can dynamically generate the `WHERE` part of a spring data query.
In order to use specifications with your spring data JPA queries, you will have to extend the `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface. So your user repository could look like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

Your search method could look like this

```
public List<User> getAllFilterByString(String text) {

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(text))
        return userRepository.findAll();

    Specification<User> specification =
            (root, query, cb) -> {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("name")), "%"+text.toLowerCase()+"%"));

                //check if the text value can be casted to long.
                //if it is possible, then add the check to the query
                try {
                    long longValue = Long.valueOf(text);
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("id"), longValue));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    //do nothing, the text is not long
                }

                //check if the text can be casted to boolean
                //if it is possible, then add the check to the query

                Boolean value = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(text) ? Boolean.TRUE :
                        "false".equalsIgnoreCase(text) ? Boolean.FALSE : null;

                if(value != null) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("isActive"), value));
                }

                return cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
            };

    return userRepository.findAll(specification);

}
```

First we start by adding the `name LIKE %text%` part of the where expression.

Next, we check if the value of the `text` variable can be cast to `long`. If it can, then we get the long value out of the string and add it to the where query.

Last we check if the `text` variable can be cast to boolean. If it can, then we add that check to the query as well.

For example, if the value of the `text` variable is *test1* the where part will be

```
WHERE name LIKE '%test1%;
```

If the value of the `text` variable is *true* then the where part will be

```
WHERE name LIKE '%true%' OR is_active = true;
```

Finally, if the value of the `text` variable is *12* then the where part will be

```
WHERE name LIKE '%12%' OR id = 12;
```

**Note:**
I added `cb.lower(root.get("name"))` and `text.toLowerCase()` to the part when we search by name in order to make the search case insensitive.

Comment: Great job!!! This is the answer that I've been looking for a long time!!! Can you explain to me how can I add some joins easly because in my case I have many nested object and I need search for all fields. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @DanielRch. can you please create a new question with your specific example so that I (and the community) can take a look at it?