# How to write a generic java function in Spring-boot for querying results,based on multiple query filters

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I was working on java using jdo where I used to write query functions like below, which queries from an Entity based on what parameters are passed to the function.
Now Im moving to spring-boot, and want to know if I can achieve the same using spring-boot.Any help or suggestions would be heartfully appreciated.Thank you!!

```
public List<Result> getQueryResult(int filter1, String filter2,Float filter3,Long id){
    Query query = new Query("select from Entity1");
    String filter = "id == "+id;
    if(filter1 != null){
      filter = filter+" && filter1 == "+filter1+";
    }
    if(filter2 != null){
    filter = filter+" && filter2 == '"+filter2+"'";
    }
    if(filter3 != null){
    filter = filter+"filter3 == "+filter3;
    }
    query.setFIlter(filter);
    List<Result> results = query.excute();
    return results;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113509/jpa-search-string-long-and-boolean/51115628#51115628) is an example of dynamically generating the where (filter) part of a JPA query using Spring data JPA.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options - you can use [JPA Criteria Builder](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) or [JPA Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

```
class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int age;
}
```

## JPA Criteria Builder

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = query.from(Person.class);

Predicate sellAlcohol = builder.ge(root.get(Person_.age), 21);
Predicate toMindy = builder.equal(root.get(Person_.firstName), "Mindy");
```

**Usage**

```
query.where(builder.and(sellAlcohol, toMindy));
em.createQuery(query.select(root)).getResultList();
```

## Specificatons

```
public PersonSpecifications {

  public static Specification<Person> sellAlcohol() {
    return new Specification<Person> {
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.ge(root.get(Person_.age), 21);
      }
    };
  }

  public static Specification<Person> toMindy() {
    return new Specification<Person> {
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.equal(root.get(Person_.firstName), "Mindy");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
personRepository.findAll(where(sellAlcohol()).and(toMindy()));
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this surely helps :)